# Efficient algorithm for searching 3D coordinate in an array

Tags: c, search, floating-point

I have a large array (>10^5 entries) of 3D coordinates r=(x, y, z), where x, y and z are floats. Which is the most efficient way to search a given coordinate r' in the array and give the array index. Note that the r' may not given with the same accuracy as r; say, if the array has stored coordinate (1.5, 0.5, 0.0) and r' is given as (1.49999, 0.49999, 0.0), the algorithm should rightly pick the coordinate. I am developing the code in C.

How can one use O(1) search capability of hash table for this purpose? Converting the coordinate into string is out of question due to accuracy related issue. Is there any particular data structure that would help in O(1) algorithm?

Thanks

OnRoadCoder

Answer (score 4):

check [R-trees](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R-tree), already implemented on some RDBMS, like SQLite, and (i think) Postgres

Comment: A tree can't do O(1), but then again, my approach cannot either unless you make the hash table balanced.

Comment: BTW - the R-Tree implementation available in most RDBMSs is 2D/2.5D only, since they're almost always based on the OpenGIS Spec, which doesn't provide true 3D support --- However, R-Trees are a very good space partioning option, if you implement your own (or find a good 3D implementation).

Answer (score 4):

In order to have "fuzzy" searching as you're describing (so you can support slight inaccuracies), you will have to sacrifice on O(1) algorithms.

That being said, there are some very good algorithms for this.  [Space partitioning](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_partitioning) (such as using an [Octree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octree) or [KD-Tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kd-tree)) is a common, popular option.

Comment: Thanks Reed. Are there GNU lib for efficient space partitioning, including Octree/KD-Tree?

Comment: ANN (LGPL) will do this, and is pretty fast: http://www.cs.umd.edu/~mount/ANN/   STANN is also good: http://sites.google.com/a/compgeom.com/stann/   These aren't space partitioning libraries as much as searching libraries (so they do the partitioning for you, and you just use them...)

Answer (score 0):

If the range of values is limited, pick the precision you want. Now, the key (1,2,3) will point to a linked list (or a fancier data structure) of all points that are within Manhattan Distance of 3 * d (d = 0.5? - depends on details) from (1,2,3). You know your application best, so you can do a better job of choosing d. Optimization approach would depend on how the data is distributed.

***EDIT:***

The weakness here is - if you have many points concentrated within a single cube, then there is little that can be done using a hash table about guaranteeing O(1) ... more like O(n) :)

Some sort of tree-based data structure can guaranteed O(log n).

Comment: This can be very difficult to do in a general purpose case - distribution of input data will either make this work, or break it horribly.

Comment: I agree. I was reinventing the wheel.

Comment: The data point is sparse, not more than 20, within a single cube (say, unit cube); but I was wondering if there are algorithm for general case. Anyway, let me try something based on tree.

Comment: If there are many points concentrated within a single cube, then you have not used the correct precision (what you call d) and/or you have not checked the precision when inserting the points into the hash table. With correct precision, there should be maximum one point in each cube.

Answer (score 0):

What you are asking sounds like [Nearest Neighbour Search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nearest_neighbor_search). One approach might be to code a [kd-tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kd_tree) (or any space partition based technique) and use that to find the nearest point to your query. But you can also go with a [hash](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locality_sensitive_hashing) based approach, which basically does what Ipthnc's answer describes, but tries to avoid bad performance for degenerate cases.

Comment: Very similar to nearest neighbor search, but not precisely; trying to find points which forms certain type of 3D geometrical clusters. Thanks for your suggestion.