# Find the nearest dot in a 2D space

Tags: algorithm

Yesterday I read a problem which can be translated into the following problem with slight modification:

The coordinate of a dot is expressed by (x, y) in a 2D space.

Input : An array of dots `ARRAY = (x1, y1), (x2, y2), (x3, y3), ..., (xn, yn)`
        and another dot `D = (xi, yi)`

Find the dot in the `ARRAY` which is nearest to `D`.

By saying "nearest", I am referring to the [Euclidian distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_distance).

---

There is an obvious solution: traverse each dot in the `ARRAY` and compute its Euclidian distance to `D`. Then, find the shortest distance. This can be done in O(N) time.

Can we do faster, say, in O(logN)? I am trying to use divide-and-conquer approach, but haven't come to a concrete idea yet.

---

Generalization of the problem: how to find the nearest dot in a K-dimensional space? Can we do it in less than O(N)?

Comment: Possibly related, except this one uses 3D space: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2095664/efficient-algorithm-for-searching-3d-coordinate-in-an-array

Comment: @Nitrodist: This is not a duplicate. The problem you posted is to search for a dot in the given array. My problem is to find the dot in the array having shortest distance to another given dot (outside the array).

Comment: Did I **say** duplicate or did I say that it was *related*?

Comment: @Nitrodist: Apologize for my fault. I misunderstood your comments.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If the array is not sorted in any way, then it is not possible to do any faster than O(n), as you have to check every point to make sure it is not closer than anything you have found so far.

You CAN do some preprocessing to sort the points or pack them into some structure, then do searches on that structure. In this case, while the preprocessing step may be slower than O(n), the individual searches may be faster. If you have many points to check against the same set of points, this can be advantageous.

Comment: Yeah, you are right. If the array is not sorted in any way, it is unlikely to do any faster than O(n).

Comment: @SiLent SoNG:
"Unlikely" is not the right word here. It is **impossible** to do any faster. You *have to* do *something* to each element to know that it isn't closer than any other you have already checked. Unless, of course you have found a point in the array that is exactly equal to the point D. Then you definitely won't find any other that is closer :).

Answer (score 3):

You can use a [Bounding Volume Hierarchy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bounding_volume_hierarchy). This does not improve on the worst-case complexity though, nor does it directly lead to an exact solution.

Answer (score 2):

I have come out with a solution in O(logN) if the dots are sorted on x coordinate.

It uses a divide-and-conquer approach. I divide the dots array based on their x coordinate in the 2D space.

Consider the 2D case.

Assume each dot is expressed in the following data structure:

```
class Point {
    public float getX();
    public float getY();
}
```

We have two inputs: dot array `ARRAY`, and another dot `D`.

Initially, we would like to partition `ARRAY` into two parts: those dots that are on the "left" of `D`, and those dots are on the "right" of `D`.

```
int pivotIndex = partition(array, 0, array.length() - 1, d);
```

After partition, the dots with index less than `pivotIndex` have x coordinate less than `d.getX()`; the dots with index equal or greater than `pivotIndex` have x coordinate equal or greater than `d.getX()`.

If all dots are on the left side of `D`, `pivotIndex` would be `array.length() - 1`. If all dots are on the right side of `D`, `pivotIndex` would be `-1`. If some dots are on the left of `D` and some dots are on the right of `D`, then `pivotIndex` would be between `0` and `array.length() - 1`. For dots having the same x coordinate as `D`, they are considered as on the "right" side.

Now, the next step is to search the nearest dot on each partition:

```
Point p1 = getNearestDot(array, 0, pivotIndex, d);
Point p2 = getNearestDot(array, pivotIndex + 1, array.length() - 1, d);

if (p1 == null) return p2;
if (p2 == null) return p1;

return nearer(p1, p2, d);
```

It is possible that all the dots in the `ARRAY` are on the left side of `D`, then p2 would be null in this case. Similarly, if all dots in the `ARRAY` are on the right side of `D`, then p1 would be null.

The algorithm of `getNearestDot` works as below:

```
// Find the nearest dot in array[low...high] inclusive which is closest to point d 
Point getNearestDot(Point[] array, int low, int high, Point d) {
    if (low > high)
        return null;
    if (low == high)
        return array[low];

    int middle = low + (high - low) >> 1;
    Point p1 = getNearestDot(array, low, middle, d);
    Point p2 = getNearestDot(array, middle + 1, high, d);

    if (p1 == null) return p2;
    if (p2 == null) return p1;

    return nearer(p1, p2, d);
}
```

And finally, the function nearer(p1, p2, d) is to return either p1 or p2, whose distance to d is shorter.

Comment: Yeah, that's the same algorithm that first came to my mind when I read this question. Note that in degenerate cases this algorithm is still linear. E.g. if all points have equal x coordinate. Personally, I would just use a simple quadtree instead.

Comment: How is that O(log(n))? Sure, it looks like a binary search which is O(log(n)), but you're always following both branches of the tree. It's at least O(n).

Answer (score 2):

Practically we can sort the points in x-coordinate, then start from the point whose x difference is most closed to the target, and we scan to both left and right, and stop scanning to one direction as soon as the next point's x difference in that direct is already bigger than smallest distance found so far.
Divide Conquer is still linear if you divide to two half but do not discard either half.